# I've encountered this problem while working with JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the value inside a class tag in HTML?

```
class="headerLogo">BHURTEL<
```

I want to change "BHURTEL" using user input string using prompt method. I tried this:

```
let name = prompt("Input your name:");     
document.getElementsByClassName('headerLogo').innerHTML = name;
```

but it didn't work! is there a way to do it? Or it's not possible?

Comment: You should always check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) first; as the plural s implies, `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like collection of elements.

Answer (score -1):

use `querySelector`:

```js
document.querySelector('headerLogo').textContent = name;
```

Comment: Invalid selector...

Answer (score -1):

here is the correct way to get the element

```js
document.querySelector(".headerLogo").innerHTML = 'name'
```